# Docker Compose with ASP.NET Core and PostgreSQL services

Tags: asp.net, postgresql, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I'm trying to connect a ASP.NET Core container to PostgreSQL official container using Docker-Compose, I've name my container as `aspnetcore-postgres` and it contains in the configuration the connection string points to the PostgreSQL container as:

```
User ID=postgres;Password=5432;Host=localhost;Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=ApplicationDbContext;Pooling=true;
```

And I use the following compose file for connection:

```
version: '2'

  services:

   web:
     image: aspnetcore-postgres
   ports:
     - "5000:5000"
   networks:
     - aspnetcoreapp-network

   postgres:
    image: postgres
   environment:
     - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 5432"
   networks:
     - aspnetcoreapp-network
   ports: 
     - "5432:5432"

   networks:
      aspnetcoreapp-network:
         driver: bridge
```

Whenever I try to run `docker-compose up`, the web application can't recognize the database container. Eventually, I only see the Postgres container in the network not the web application container. I'm using Docker for Windows RC4.

Anyone can recognized that where I'm doing the wrong step?

Comment: Any errors coming from docker?

Comment: No, I do not see any error from Docker.